# Dot Product function in C language

Tags: c

I am looking for some help in writing function below.

It looks like:
`double dot_product(double v[],double u[],int n)`, 
where n is length of the vector

Is it correct?

```
double dot_product(double v[], double u[], int n)
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
result += v[i]*u[i];
}
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to declare a result variable, initialize it to zero, accumulate into it, and then return it.

```
double dot_product(double v[], double u[], int n)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result += v[i]*u[i];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What if vectors have different length?

Comment: The dot product is not defined in that case.

Comment: As example vector A[1, 2, 2]. Length of A is 3. B[0,0,1]. Length of B is 1. Dot product is defined? In general. They must be in the same n-dimensional space? I mean, that dot product isn't defined when we want to use it for vectors: C[A,B,C] and D[A2,B2,C2,D2]?

Comment: @user3127826 Example of what?

Comment: The length of `B` is 3. Do you have a problem with the code in my answer?

Comment: Sometimes I have trouble with the interpretation of the vector. I mean that I don't have to care about "physical length"? I mean square root of the x1^2 + x2^2 +...+ xn^2. In this case by the length you understand number of elements in a row?

Comment: The dot product operator is defined for two vectors in the same n-dimensional space

Comment: So in that case length is the same what number of dimensions of space? Howerwer thank you very much for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question then?

Comment: Yes. Thank you and Marry Christmas ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `result` is global variable then change return type of function to `void` and place a braces around the body of the function;

```
void dot_product(double v[], double u[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         result += v[i]*u[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan; Yes. [Global variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).

Comment: Why would you use a global variable?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan; I do not want to use it. I guessed that OP declared it as global.

Comment: @haccks Global variable would be dreadful here. Don't suggest that. More likely the asker is used to Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

the fixed code

```
double dot_product(double v[], double u[], int n) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += v[i]*u[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hlo. try this

You did two mistakes are

1. Missed { at the first line.
2. Missed to tell the return type.

   double dot_product(double v[], double u[], int n)
   {
      int i;
      double result =0.0;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
       result += v[i]*u[i];
      }
   return result;
   }